# How to style a label to stay on top of the input

Tags: html, css

I was just wondering whether I can place a styled label on top of an input element. I've seen images placed inside input elements to show what sort of input is accepted by that element. for an example in a login form the user name is represented with a user icon and the password is represented with a key icon. Is there a way I can place a label like that.!

[Sample image which shows an input element with an icon image in it!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/do80v.png)

Answer (score 1):

you can set the background image for it.

e.g.

```
.label {
    background: transparent url('image path') left top no-repeat;
}
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/E3cjx/)

Comment: I think you've understood the question the wrong way! What I want to do is place a label ontop of an input element!

Answer (score 1):

For icons just add `background-image` to an input and small padding, so your text won't be collided with the icon:

```
<input style="background-image: url(key.png) top left no-repeat;
              padding-left: 20px;">
```

If you want a placeholder text, there's a `placeholder` attribute.

Comment: Can you explain me on how to put a label that way!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `:after` and `@font-face`.Please click [here](http://www.w3cplus.com/w3cplusDemo/demos/LoginRegistrationForm.html).